# Android app problem: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 207: invalid start byte

Tags: android, django, unicode, utf-8, decode

So I have two ubuntu servers stage and dev, and one single API for android, IOS and web front on reactjs.

I get this error when I try to upload a photo to my server from ANDROID app, basically I can upload the same photo to DEV server from Postman and IOS, but I keep getting this error when I try uploading from android. But from the same android app I can upload this exact photo to stage server and prod server, so basically nothing wrong with android app, but something is wrong on the server, even tho it correctly works with IOS and postman and web app.

I believe that the code and settings are almost the same on both servers, so I have no idea where is the problem...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project/.local/share/virtualenvs/blabla_backend-B039YcMy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/project/blabla_backend/dating/middleware.py", line 144, in call
    body_repl = str(request.body, 'utf-8').replace('\n', '') if request.body else 'null'
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 207: invalid start byte
```

Uploading a photo from android just like from other apps, but it just dissapears and I get this error in django logs. But still same android app can somehow upload photos to other servers without this bug...

Comment: You say the settings are "almost" the same. It might help if you include both sets of settings in the question and highlight the differences, rather than hoping that someone light guess.
The actual error means that you don't have a UTF-8 encoded string, but something else as a character can't start with the byte value 0xff in UTF-8.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts The problem is that I have a large django app that has multiple apps in it, and to include both sets of settings and post them here would be unreal. It would take me like 3 hours to just check everything on both servers and see the differences, but I might do that later
Strange that I get this decode error only on this server and only with android, while this completely same code in middleware.py is on the other server and this utf-8 codec works fine there